# A server side library to make javascript IE compatible

Tags: javascript, node.js, internet-explorer

I have been looking for a server side library that is able to capture all scripts used on an HTML page, and convert them to IE (<9) compatible (e.g., handling things like getter / setters, missing types etc.). However I am not having much luck finding one.

Does anyone know if such a library? Am I dreaming thinking I will be able to find / build such a thing?

My preference is first node.js, second POSIX, however any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Edit: I think it is worth noting that I am not referring to something which handles differences in the IE DOM (although that would be helpful), but rather something that handles javascript language differences.

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of this, but this won't handle conversion of things like Object.defineProperty...

Comment: Besides that, it does not rewrite your JS to add support for things like accessors. That's far from trivial after all - even IDEs often don't properly handle all the magic stuff you can do with JS when it comes to code completion. So imagine how hard it is to do that when the resulting code must actually be executable.

Comment: 1. Far from trivial... this is why I am looking for someone who has done it already :D
2. The code rewrite is the reason I want it on the server...
3. I think since something like coffee script is able to be compiled to javascript, and some tools exist to convert js to coffee, this may be a possible solution vector. I would prefer something a little more dedicated however...

Answer (score 0):

There are what you call shims, like [ES5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim). Though not thoroughly complete, they create support for ES5 functionality for legacy browsers. This is client-side code though.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer... I have looked at these as well (as well as moderniser), but have absolutely come to the conclusion that I need a server side solution. I believe this is the only solution which will be able to completely solve this.